# Updating SQL table column based on row difference in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a table with some missing values that looks like something like this:

**TABLE**

```
+-------------+------------+---------+----------+
| Location    | date       | new_vax | total_vax|
+-------------+------------+---------+----------+
| Afghanistan | 01-01-2020 |  NULL   |  NULL    |
| Afghanistan | 01-02-2020 |  NULL   |  5000    |
| Afghanistan | 01-05-2020 |  NULL   |  7000    |
| Afghanistan | 01-09-2020 |  1000   |  8000    |
| Afghanistan | 01-10-2020 |  1000   |  9000    |
+-------------+------------+---------+----------+
```

There are multiple `locations` and each has a different date range, and a different date where `total_vax` is no longer NULL, and an uneven number of days between each update for `total_vax`

For each location and date, I want to update the `new_vax` column to be the difference between the `total_vax` rows for that date and the date before it, so the result would look like

**DESIRED RESULT**

```
+-------------+------------+---------+----------+
| Location    | date       | new_vax | total_vax|
+-------------+------------+---------+----------+
| Afghanistan | 01-01-2020 |  NULL   |  NULL    |
| Afghanistan | 01-02-2020 |  5000   |  5000    |
| Afghanistan | 01-05-2020 |  2000   |  7000    |
| Afghanistan | 01-09-2020 |  1000   |  8000    |
| Afghanistan | 01-10-2020 |  1000   |  9000    |
+-------------+------------+---------+----------+
```

I've tried a few things but they've all seemed to fail for one reason or another, and I'm not 100% sure on why.

The latest thing I tried was:

**ATTEMPTED SOLUTION**

```sql
WITH cte AS (
         SELECT location, date, new_vax,
                COALESCE(LAG(total_vax) OVER (PARTITION BY location 
                                              ORDER BY date),
                  NULL) AS prev_total_vax, 
                total_vax
           FROM #temp_death_vax
  
)

UPDATE #temp_death_vax
   SET #temp_death_vax.new_vax = sub.fixed_new_vax 
  FROM #temp_death_vax
  JOIN (
       SELECT [location],[date],
              total_vax,
              prev_total_vax,
              COALESCE(total_vax - prev_total_vax,new_vax) AS fixed_new_vax,
              new_vax
         FROM cte
        WHERE total_vax IS NOT NULL
          AND new_vax IS NULL
        ) AS sub
    ON #temp_death_vax.location = sub.location 
       AND #temp_death_vax.date = sub.date
```

But I still get a lot of NULL values for `fixed_new_vax`.

Would love any help or insight. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @mosefaq, why total_vax on 01-09-2020 turns from 7000 to 8000

Comment: @Junjie that was a typo in the question from when I made a change, my bad. Editted it for clarification now

Comment: I see, @mosefaq. Your window function seems good then.  I have deleted my answer in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In certain situations a table expression is *updatable* so you can do

```
with cte as (
  select new_vax, 
    IsNull(total_vax - Lag(total_vax) over(partition by location order by date), total_vax) nv
  from t
)
update cte
set new_vax = nv;
```

Comment: So this solution from @Stu does work, and turns out that my original solution worked as well, though this is cleaner.

The reason I was still getting null values is that there were still some total_vax values in the middle that were NULL which was causing problems.